# Data Factory - Azure File Linked Service - Managed Identity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-managed-identity

When creating a new linked service for data factory I am able to select "Managed Identity" for connection to storage account\blob but this isn't an option for same storage account\file.

Is this a known limitation?

**Works ok with blob:**

[image]

**No option for Managed Identity for file share:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Azure file storage** connector in Azure data factory linked service currently supports only below authentication:

1. Account key authentication
2. Shared access signature authentication

Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-file-storage?tabs=data-factory#connector-configuration-details) for more information on linked service for Azure File storage connector.